# SQL substring or select from right?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder if someone could explain this to me.

```
Where substring(t1.MemoTypeCode,1,1) = N'_'
```

This will take MemoTypecode where first character is _

Now I am trying to do something similar, but check if the last character is _

I've seen something similar here: [T-SQL Substring - Last 3 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359772/t-sql-substring-last-3-characters) but unfortunately, without luck.

```
Where RIGHT(t1.MemoTypeCode, 1) = N'_'
```

this is supposed to take MemoTypeCode where last character is _ but is not working

Entire code:

```
Select t1.MemoTypeCode, t1.Description
  From T_MemoType t1
  --Where substring(t1.MemoTypeCode,1,1) = N'_'  This will take MemoTypecode where first character is _

  --Where RIGHT(t1.MemoTypeCode, 1) = N'_'  this is supposed to take MemoTypeCode where last character is _ but is not working
  Order by t1.MemoTypeCode
```

Any idea why substring is working correctly while the Where Right is not working?

Comment: What character is `RIGHT(t1.MemoTypeCode, 1)`? Probably a space. That would work fine if the final character was actually an underscore.

Comment: Perhaps you have some trailing white space. Try trimming that field before grabbing it's substring: `Where RIGHT(TRIM(t1.MemoTypeCode), 1) = N'_' `

Comment: There may also be some unprintable characters like TABS

Comment: The last character is an underline

Comment: How have you determined that? Have you actually executed `SELECT RIGHT(t1.MemoTypeCode, 1)`?

Comment: I've added test_ in the table which should be returned when I execute the SQL proc.

Comment: @JNevill Trim is not working for some reason. Can't execute the SQL proc
`TRIM is not a recognized built-in function`

Comment: Just because that's what you inserted doesn't mean that's what you have. You may be using `char` instead of `varchar` and getting trailing spaces added for example. You need to actually select it out.

Comment: Apologies. Use `RTRIM()` in sql server

Comment: @JNevill Wow, That solved the problem. please, put it in an answer and I vote it as answer ;)

Comment: If that solved the problem then that means the last character was a space. So you need to investigate why. Quite likely you are using an inappropriate fixed length data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have some trailing white space in your field (It's hard to spot by eye). This could be due to a bad data load, or possible the use of an CHAR/NCHAR where the allocated memory block is padded with space to fill the space (although I would think that `RIGHT()` would be smart enough to trim a CHAR).

Try trimming that field before grabbing it's substring:

```
WHERE RIGHT(RTRIM(t1.MemoTypeCode), 1) = N'_'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the problem...

```
with cte (val) as (Select N'_test' union all
                   select N'test_')

Select val
     , case when left(val,1) = N'_' then 1 else 0 end as startsWithUnderscore
     , case when right(val,1) = N'_' then 1 else 0 end as EndsWithUnderscore
from cte;

+----+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
|    |  val  | startsWithUnderscore | EndsWithUnderscore |
+----+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | _test |                    1 |                  0 |
|  2 | test_ |                    0 |                  1 |
+----+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

RexTester: http://rextester.com/NDCKJ46846

Comment: If you don't understand the problem perhaps refrain from answering? You can wait for clarification or just vote to close the question as "not clear what you are asking".

Comment: I'll disagree.  with the above showing the proof is that left and right work.  the question is: "Any idea why substring is working correctly while the Where Right is not working?"  Therefore the question is flawed Right is working. Thus the problem stems in a broke function on his server, or in the data.  I'll take the downvote, but proof that a function is working as desired proves false an assumption in the question.

Comment: That's a reason to vote to close not post a half baked answer. There's a specific close vote reason for missing a MCVE.

Answer (score -2):

_ is a very special. It represents any one. Please use [*] instead. like: 
Where substring(t1.MemoTypeCode,1,1) = N'[*]' 
Try

Comment: This is only relevant in `LIKE` not `=`